# Llamar a Array devuelto por un metodo

Tags: java, array

Tengo este método, donde quiero usar el array devuelto, pero me da un error:

```html
 public static int[] validarRespuestas (String[] preguntas, String[] nombres, String[][] matrizNotas){

        int aciertos=0, fallos=0;
        
        for (int fil = 0; fil < nombres.length; fil++) {
            for (int col = 0; col < matrizNotas[0].length; col++)  {
                if (matrizNotas[fil][col].equals(preguntas[col])){
                    aciertos++;
                }
                
                else {
                    fallos++;
                }
            }
        }

        System.out.println("Los aciertos son: "+aciertos);
        System.out.println("Los fallos son: "+fallos);
        
        int[] resultado = {aciertos, fallos}; 

        return resultado;

    }
```

```html
public static void main(String[] args){
int[] val=validarRespuestas();
}
```

Me dice esto al querer usar el array devuelto por el metodo;

method validarRespuestas in class Pruebas cannot be applied to given types;
  required: String[],String[],String[][]
  found: no arguments
  reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En la llamada que estás haciendo al método: `validarRespuestas` no le estás pasando los parámetros que espera.

Ese método espera tres parámetros: `String[] preguntas, String[] nombres, String[][]` matrizNotas, pero cuando lo invocas en el método main no le estás pasando nada.

Comment: solucionado! gracias

Comment: Recuerda marcar mi respuesta, gracias.